# Django rest framework APIView Pagination EmptyPage

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination

Successfully made pagination work and here is my code:

```
from rest_framework import pagination


class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 10
    page_query_param = 'p'


class PaginationHandlerMixin(object):
    @property
    def paginator(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_paginator'):
            if self.pagination_class is None:
                self._paginator = None
            else:
                self._paginator = self.pagination_class()
        else:
            pass
        return self._paginator
    
    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset):
        if self.paginator is None:
            return None
        return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)
    
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        assert self.paginator is not None
        return self.paginator.get_paginated_response(data)
```

and this my view class:

```
class OrderOntrackViewPaginated(APIView, PaginationHandlerMixin):
    queryset = Order.objects.filter(~Q(staged__iexact="offtrack")).values().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def get(self, request):
        results = self.paginate_queryset(self.queryset)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(results, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

my question is if I can handle `EmptyPage` so if max page is for example 3 and user puts `...?p=4` in the request, I could return a valid response.

Answer (score 0):

I think could be easy to use `ListAPIView` like this:

```py
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class OrderOntrackViewPaginated(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.exclude(staged__iexact="offtrack").order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    http_method_names = ['get']
```

I hope this help you. Regards!